# inserting data in many to many relationship in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, insert, many-to-many, relationship

I have two tables (users , messages) which there is many to many relationship for them.
i want to add new messages in message table and allocate massages to current users.
Also i insert data like below:

```
Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage("MessageText", "DateTime");
newMessage.Users.Add(new User{..... });
context.SaveChange();
```

this code will execute a query which add a new user in users table while the users table has some specified users and i don't want to add new user but as i mentioned i want to add new messages in message table and allocate massages to current users.

how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating a new `User` object with an existing primary key. When `SaveChanges()` is called EF detects the changes of the entities its already tracking and new entities added. Since your new `User` object was not tracked by EF, it tries to insert it.

You need to explicitly tell EF that the created user is an existing one. To do that you need to [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487214.aspx) it.

```
Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage("MessageText", "DateTime");

var user = new User{ Id = "foo" };
context.Users.Attach(user);

newMessage.Users.Add(user);    
context.SaveChange();
```